# Can't install new ubuntu app center in 23.10

Tags: gnome, upgrade, updates, software-center, snap-store

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10, and everything seems fine except that Ubuntu Software hasn't updated to the new Flutter-based App Center. I tried running `snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10` like I saw in other answers, but I simply got the message `snap "snap-store" has no updates available`. I also tried reinstalling snap-store; nothing. I tried installing the edge release of the snap store but the App Center simply wouldn't launch. Strangely, on snapcraft.io it says the snap-store stable release was last updated 27 April 2023 even though 23.10 came out in October. The old Ubuntu Software center is very sluggish for me, so I would greatly appreciate being able to install the new App Center.

Comment: You might want to read details about the snap-store snap at (https://snapcraft.io/snap-store) which already states this is the GNOME-based version, not the Flutter version.  From what I know with Ubuntu from backchannels, the Flutter implementation is not complete yet, so I would not expect there to be a version of the Flutter installer fully functional until a full Flutter release happens - it's still in development

Answer (score 0):

There was [an issue over the past day](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-snap-store/40559/5?u=johnandmegh) where the previous version of the App Center / Snap Store got pushed out to 23.10 users. It was fixed at some point during the past ~8 hours, so refreshing the snap using the `latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10` channel should now bring you the new App Center (note that you may need to kill `gnome-software` to enable it to refresh).